# Explanation needed about getChildrenUnmodifiable

Tags: java, javafx, root

I'm having trouble with root modification in JavaFX.

A class loads an FXML and creates a scene, but I'm not able to use the `getChildren()` function, there is just `getChildrenUnmodifiable()`.

The first container in `login.fxml` is a `StackPane`, maybe `StackPane` doesn't support it, like some controls?

I probably misunderstand how JavaFX works.

I have created a test application to see if other classes of my project are causing the problem:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent rootScene = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("login.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(rootScene, 900, 500);
    //rootScene.getChildrenUnmodifiable()
}
```

Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out in the other answer, `Parent.getChildren()` is a `protected` method. However, it is overridden in `StackPane` (in fact in `Pane`, so this is true for all `Pane` subclasses) and the visibility is broadened to `public`.

So, since the root of your FXML is actually a `StackPane`, all you have to do is change the compile-time type of `root`:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    StackPane rootScene = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("login.fxml"));
    rootScene.getChildren().add(...);
    Scene scene = new Scene(rootScene, 900, 500);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a code-samplet in addition to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Parent.getChildren()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html#getChildren--) is a `protected` method; in order to call it, your code must either be a subclass of `Parent` or in the same package as `Parent`. This was evidently done to prevent client code from being able to directly change the children collection.

However, as the answer by @James_D indicates, there are subclasses of `Parent` that do have a `public` version of `getChildren()`. The [Pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) class, for example, does (and `StackPane` is a subclass of `Pane`). If all your children subclass from `Pane`, you can replace `Parent` in your code with `Pane`.